# No adapter attached; skipping layout while using volley

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i am using volley here to get data from xampp server through my api(works fine on postman)
but getting this on running the code,Toast defined onErrorResponse is shown on display as soon as the app opens and app does not crash.
read many solutions to this ,many were related to fragments..i didn't use fragments...
also in my code i think when i have called the setAdapter method on recyclerview ,i have just above it defined myAdapter

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(data);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

main activity.java

```
package com.example.poetryapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.poetryapp.adapter.MyAdapter;
import com.example.poetryapp.model.PoetryModel;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.poetry_recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));


        loaddata();
    }

    private void loaddata() {

        String url = "http://192.168.137.198/poetryapi/getPoetryRead.php.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                PoetryModel data[]=gson.fromJson(response,PoetryModel[].class);

                MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.e("success",response);
            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



    }
    }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
package com.example.poetryapp.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.poetryapp.R;
import com.example.poetryapp.model.PoetryModel;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.viewHolder> {

    PoetryModel data[];

    public MyAdapter(PoetryModel[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poetry_list_view,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.t1_name.setText(data[position].getPoet_name());
        holder.t2_data.setText(data[position].getPoetry_data());
        holder.t3_date_time.setText(data[position].getDate_time());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView t1_name,t2_data,t3_date_time;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            t1_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poetName);
            t2_data=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poetryData);
            t3_date_time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poet_dateTime);

        }
    }


}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/poetry_recyclerView"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat error message

```
2021-09-09 09:38:45.963 29496-29496/com.example.poetryapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2021-09-09 09:38:46.004 29496-29496/com.example.poetryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.poetryapp, PID: 29496
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:944)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
        at com.example.poetryapp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:53)
        at com.example.poetryapp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:46)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7868)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:349)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817) 
        at com.example.poetryapp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:53) 
        at com.example.poetryapp.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:46) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29) 
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7868) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

my url returns this

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "record is not empty",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "poetry_data": "shdoqw djwaiood aand od sodnh asisd d ashd asidhas das das doaisdhas dsa d as diwdhw xs dw wh codfj e",
            "poet_name": "abcd efg",
            "date_time": "2021-09-02 08:32:10"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "poetry_data": "updating this",
            "poet_name": "abc",
            "date_time": "2021-09-04 10:38:22"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "poetry_data": "aaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc",
            "poet_name": "abc",
            "date_time": "2021-09-02 10:11:08"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "poetry_data": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            "poet_name": "aa",
            "date_time": "2021-09-03 10:16:08"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "poetry_data": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            "poet_name": "aa",
            "date_time": "2021-09-03 10:16:22"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "poetry_data": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            "poet_name": "aa",
            "date_time": "2021-09-03 10:17:04"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "poetry_data": "",
            "poet_name": "",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:19:39"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "poetry_data": "",
            "poet_name": "",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:23:38"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "poetry_data": "",
            "poet_name": "",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:24:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "poetry_data": "bhdjasvjguuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
            "poet_name": "nameisname",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:29:59"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "poetry_data": "bhdjasvjguuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
            "poet_name": "abara",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:42:43"
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "poetry_data": "bhdjasvjguuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu",
            "poet_name": "kkkkkkkhgvghytu",
            "date_time": "2021-09-06 09:52:21"
        }
    ]
}
```

the second error is related to gson but i dont know how to write it correctly to parse json to gson for the structure my url returns.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

after this line in your main activity?

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: tried now    `recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`                                                                                           but now my error logcat has new error,updated code above sir

Comment: Well the error now with getting the data from the api it is a parsing error which means you are getting the data with wrong response because your actual data inside the big object yourrespons.yourdata . Now I said that just to explain why you are facing this error and to avoid it in future.Now you can solve this error by following what @Abhishek Ippakayal said.  And in future you can go to this website  to write your response. https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Also Just a small advice to write more practical code to follow MVVM structure with repositories and retrofit with view model also, take a look to view binding it's easier to get the views than findviewbyid. Google has a great example it's fine at first not to understand all of it by time you will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your error log and your api response json, you are parsing it wrong.
Your response class should look like this.

```java
class PoetryResponse() {
   @Serializable("status")
   String status;

   @Serializable("message")
   String message;

   @Serializable("data")
   Poetry[] data;

}
```

Your data object class

```java
class Poetry() {
 @Serializable("id")
   String id;

   @Serializable("poetry_data")
   String poetryData;

   @Serializable("poet_name")
   String poetName;
   
   @Serializable("date_time")
   String dateTime;
}
```

Get response from json with below code

```java
PoetryResponse poetryResponse = gson.fromJson(response,PoetryResponse.class);
```

Now pass the arraylist of poetry like below in your adapter

```java
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(poetryResponse.data);
```